# Trouble with -n in sed command with Mac

Tags: shell, sed

I'm writing a script using `sed` to look for a string in one file - **temp.txt** (a version number) and take this string and update the version number in another file. Here is the relevant code snippet.

```
new=$(sed -n '/version: /p' temp.txt)  
sed -i .bk "s/version: [.0-9]*/version: $new/" file2.txt
```

The problem I'm having is that the variable `new` doesn't take just the one line with the version number on it, but instead takes the whole file, **file2.txt**. This leads me to believe that the `-n` part of the command isn't working, as this should suppress the printing of all lines but those with the string `version` in them.

I think this could be a problem with the version of `sed` I am using (on a mac). Alternatively I could be using the `sed` command wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

I'd rather not update my version of `sed`, since this script will not just be running on my computer. So any workarounds would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: The -n option doesn't do what you think it does, on Mac *Nix or Linux. You should consult the man pages for more detail.

Comment: Works for me, on a mac. Simplify; try to get `sed -n '/version: /p' temp.txt` working first.

Comment: @Beta Hmmmm this has confused me. I haven't managed your suggestion of getting `sed -n '/version: /p' temp.txt` to work. That command alone still prints out the whole of the text file temp.txt. Whaaaat? It's as if the whole file is being considered as one line.

Comment: When you say whole file, how many lines are we talking about?

Comment: Only five or so. This is just a test file I'm working with at the moment, but the real thing is likely to be short too.

Comment: Sed doesn't work well with old school mac style line endings, on the off chance that your file is using them. Try `$ file temp.txt`. If it says `temp.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators` then that's your problem.

Comment: And `tr '\015' '\012' <temp.txt | sed -n '/version: /p'` would fix that.

Comment: @Dean, am I the only one who can work with UNIX for years and still not know about tricks like that?

Comment: @Beta I have the feeling that there are hundreds of very simple UNIX tricks that would make my life much easier, and yet I will never stumble across them :P

Comment: You could also use awk if it's not your line endings: `new=$(awk '/version:/ {print $2}' temp.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you `temp.txt` looks something like this:

```
# some text
version: 3.14
# more text
```

And your `file2.txt` similar. Only one "version:" exists.

If so you could use following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
new=$(cat temp.txt | grep version: | sed "s/ //g" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
sed -i "bk" -E "s/version:.*/version: ${new}/" file2.txt
```

First command finds line in which version is written. I am using `sed` to remove any extra space, and `cut` to extract the version number. With this command version number could also be "3.6.7a" for example.

In the second command I am replacing a line in which old version is written. Notice how I do not care about what is behind "version:" string because I will replace it with my new version number. Also I am saving a backup of `file2.txt` into `file2.txt.bk`.